# How to rename file using CMD "Track ?.mp3" to "T00?.mp3"

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-rename

I have multiple mp3 file like this:

`Track [number of track].mp3` eg. `Track 1.mp3` - `Track 11.mp3`

I want to rename them to:

`T00[number of track]` eg. `T001.mp3` - `T011.mp3`

I have tried to rename 1-9 tracks with this:

```
ren "Track ?.mp3" "T00   ?.mp3"
```

but I got space in filename (`T00   1.mp3`)

Update: I'm trying to write the code to remove space this is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%G in ("T00   ?.mp3") do (

pause

echo -----------------------In loop----------------------------
echo Working with "%%G"

pause

set str=%%G
echo str is = "%str%"

pause

set str=%str:   =0% //replace "   " with 0 
echo 2str is = "%str%"
pause

ren "%%~G" "%str%"

)
```

Message I got is:

```
-----------------------In loop----------------------------

working with "C:\test\T00   1.mp3"

str = ""

2str = ""

A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.


.
.
.
```

I don't know what I wrong this is my fist time I using Batch Script

Comment: This may help http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace You should be able to replace the whitespace with nothing

Comment: @DaveRook I don't know how to write bat file would you write it for me please?

Comment: No, I'm not here to do your work! I've given you a link which shows how to do string manipulation which should help

Comment: I don’t know why there was a downvote. The question is interesting and surely a common problem. But I have no idea how to solve it in windows. In Linux no problem.

Comment: There are plenty of resources for learning how to write “BAT” files on the Internet (and I suspect some of them are useful); you can find thousands of examples just here on Super User. I’ll give you a hint: type `help setlocal` (or `setlocal /?`) and try to understand what `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` means. Then figure out whether it makes sense to use `!str!` instead of `%str%`. A more general bit of advice is that you shouldn’t let a script ***do*** anything until you have the logic debugged, so you know it’s going to do the right thing. For example, replace `ren …` with `echo ren …`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using PowerShell with [Regex replace](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/08/29/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/) and [Format string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx)

```
$strPath = "C:\my\folder\*.mp3"

Get-Childitem $strPath | ForEach-Object { 
    $onlyNumbers = $_.Basename -replace ".*\D+",""  
    $WithZeros = "{0:D3}" -f [int]$onlyNumbers
    $fileName = "T$WithZeros.mp3"
    Rename-Item $_ $fileName
    }
```

The key parts are `-replace "^\D+",""` which searches all non-digits from the beginning of the filename (but without the extension) and removes them.  Second, the script appends as many zeros as needed with `"{0:D3}" -f`. Rest is easy stuff.

Read [both](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/08/29/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/) [linked](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx) sources if you want to know more.

```
Old name          New name
Track 1.mp3       T001.mp3
Track 11.mp3      T011.mp3
Track 111.mp3     T111.mp3
```

**Edit:** Fixed small RegEx mistake. Before `99 ballons 01.mp3` becomes `T9901.mp3`.
Now it's `01 » 001 » T001.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Linux or Mac OSX to solve your problem, you could do:

```
count=1
for i in $(ls -v); do
  number=$(printf "%05d" $count)
  ((count++))
  mv $i T00$number.mp3
done
```

I have tested it on 25 files that I have previously created with this command

```
for ((i=1; i<=25; i++)); do touch "Track $i.mp3"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps Total Commander (windows) has great multi-rename tool (select desired files then Ctrl+M).